# Field Size using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm immporting a csv file with column headers:

```
 ID     ProductNumber     ProductName
 1234    A298384          Whatchamacallit
 3949    A293939          Whatchamacallit_Extra
```

I only need the ID and ProductNumber, when I map the file, I set ProductName to 'ignore'

When the package runs, it errors with the mesage that ProductName will truncate. I don't 
understand why its erroring if I set the mapping to 'ignor'

I've also tried to import and have included ProductName, setting the field to Nvarchar (4000), it still errors. I've checked the file, there is no product name more than 54 characters.

I'm using SQL 2005.

Any insight would be helpful

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some kind of "Flat File Source" as the source connection for your data flow.  If so, when you click into it and view columns; is the Productname unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import the third column, go to `advanced tab` in your `connection manager` and delete the last row.

Another way would be to ignore the errors occuring in the `error output tab` in your flat file task (ingore truncation and failure), but i advice you to use what i wrote above.

Comment: I did as you suggested and deleted the last column, however when I go to preview, the ProductName becomes part of the ProductNumber field so the ProductNumber is now > A298384,Whatchamacallit.

Comment: The column delimiter is Comma {,}  Text qualifier is False.

Comment: When you click on `advanced tab` again, use `{CR}{LF}` as delimiter for the **last** column(ProductNumber) - maybe this works

Comment: This is the column delimited on the last column.

Comment: But to be clear because it is not shown above: your csv file is comma seperated?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15464/discussion-between-stb-and-stan)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to go into the Advanced section of the flat file connection manager and set the field length for the last field to something higher than the default 50 that is set for string values if you don't override.  Since you say that 54 is your longest data width for that last column use at least that value.

To find where to change this, open the connection manager editor by double clicking the flat file connection.  In the box on the left there are four choices "General", "Columns", "Advanced", and "Preview".  You will want to click Advanced, then highlight your "ProductName" column, then in the box on the right find "OutputColumnWidth" and set it to at least 54.